# Oscillations of $x^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I was messing around on [Wolfram|Alpha here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%5E1%2Fx) when I happened to look at the graph of $x^{1/x}$.

It appears to me that both real values and imaginary values oscillate between $\pm\infty$ near $x=0$ from the left side.

It also seems as though the graph is perfectly stable for $x>0$.

The graph also seems perfectly stable around $x<-0.5$ or something.

What could explain this odd behavior?

And what determines if something is oscillating?  I can clearly tell it is oscillating by the graph, but is there a sort of definition that I can use to determine where the function stops oscillating and stabilizes?  I'm sorry if I use the wrong words.

Comment: Some of this is probably a computational artifact. For negative $x$, ask yourself what $x^{1/x}$ can mean. For rational $x$, interpreting $x^{1/x}$ is relatively clear and sometimes real; for irrational $x$, we are well and truly in the complex plane.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.  @SimonS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like that $x^{1/x}$ has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $0$. Observe that
$ \log x^{1/x} = \log x/x
$
[image: $log x/x$]
The limit
$$ \lim_{x \uparrow 0} \frac{\log x}{x} = \infty
$$
Any small variation of argument makes the function $e^{\log x/x} = x^{1/x}$ exhibit oscillatory behaviour, as seen on the right side of this graph
[image: exponential]

Comment: Oh, thank you.  I found it odd that we use the word singularity, I am more familiar with the physics definition of singularity, but it does make sense.

Comment: Could you define what oscillating is exactly?

Comment: @Simple Art The function $e^x$ is periodic on the imaginary line $i\mathbb{R}$. Therefore it is oscillating.

Comment: @HenryW26 Thank you, that is very helpful.

Comment: May you please explain what is this color graph.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla It is a [domain colour graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring)

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla No. Unfortunately this graph is for one variable only.